# Delphi XE: Why some items in File->New->Other->ActiveX are grayed out?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I wanted to create a new ASP.NET project using Delphi XE, but I'm facing the issue in the Title. Almost all icons in the right box are grayed out (disabled).

I don't understand it, because my Delphi installation is broken, or they are disabled for some reason?

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

[image: New project wizard]

Answer (score 3):

Because you first need to create a suitable project (ActiveX object or Type Library which are not greyed then those greyed items will be available.